# Checking a bash variable against multiple values

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting

I want to check input parameters in my Bash script. There can be a lot of combinations, so I decided to use a construction like this:

```
if  ( [[ "$2" = "(PARAM1|PARAM2|PARAM3)" && "$3" = "(PARAM11|PARAM22|PARAM33)" ]] )
```

I expected that this line will check which parameter is specified (there can be  input combinations like `PARAM1 PARAM22` or `PARAM11 PARAM3`, etc.).

But it doesn't work. Should I use arrays or just need to try another syntaxes?

Comment: you forked a subshell for nothing and you should use regular expression match here `=~`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to re-read the bash man page's sections on "Compound commands" and "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS" (caps per the man page).  Your question puts the condition inside a subshell, which is unnecessary.,

If you want to match arguments (`$2`, `$3`, etc) against regular expressions, you can use a format like this:

```
if [[ $2 =~ ^(foo|bar)$ ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

Or:

```
if [[ $2 =~ ^(foo|bar)$ ]] && [[ $3 =~ ^(baz|flarn)$ ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

That said, a *regular expression* isn't really needed here.  A regex uses more CPU than a simple pattern match.  I might handle this using `case` statements:

```
case "$2" in
  foo|bar)
    case "$3" in
      glurb|splat)
      # do something
      ;;
    esac
    ;;
  baz)
    # do something else
    ;;
esac
```

The exact way you handle parameters depends on what you actually need to do with them, which you haven't shared in your question.  If you update your question to include more detail, I'd be happy to update this answer. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I've tried to use `case` in my script and it works ok :)

Comment: That's great, I'm glad I could help.  Please feel free to click the checkmark beside my answer in order to close the question.